# iPhone:How to create thread running in the background always?

Tags: iphone

I want to initiate a separate thread apart from main thread and do some operations continuously even when my app is closed. I tried `detachNewThreadSelector`, but it doesn't work continuously and that too it needs my app to be launched.

And whenever I don't need it, I want to stop the thread as well. It is possible in Android, don't know how to do in iOS. How can I achieve it, could someone guide me on this? I am developing on iOS 4.3 SDK.

Comment: @Olli: Your edit removed an important sentence that needs to be treated in an answer. Please restore that sentence.

Comment: @DarkDust: I removed repetition of that information; first sentence is telling same thing.

Comment: @Olli: May bad, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a thread on a stock OS iOS device that will run in the background always.  Some types of apps, such as for VOIP, audio play/record and GPS monitoring, can register for callbacks when the app is in the background.

Comment: Thank you! Lets say, my application is launched and my program creates a Thread using detachNewThreadSelector and does some process under the thread call back function. Meanwhile, i close my application and come to device Home screen on iOS 4.x, does the process going under the Thread will be running until it finishes the task (or) will close the thread and operations once my app is closed?

Comment: @Getsy - When you "close" an iOS app, all of the threads in its process address space are suspended or killed by the OS (except possibly for those registered for special callbacks).  A task in progress may be given some limited amount of time to finish before it is killed.

Comment: Wow! That may not be useful for me. Then why Apple does say and provide that as Thread, i don't know!!